# Buttons all the way to the right do not work on iPad

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode8

Currently attempting to convert an iPhone application to also work on the iPad.  I am running into an issue where the buttons all the way on the right, do not work when clicked on the iPad.  It looks like since the buttons are shifted more to the right than on the iPhone, they no longer become clickable.  Buttons to the right work fine on the iPhone.  Buttons to the left work fine on both systems.  Any help on correct setting to fix this issue would be appreciated.  Attached is a sample button that does not work:

[image]

If I missed writing something or need more detail, please let me know.

Environment: Xcode 8.2.1, Objective-C (Not using swift)

Comment: The most probable cause is that the button is outside the bounds of some ancestor view. Pause your app in the debugger and run this debugger command: `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`. Copy the output and paste it as code into your question.

Comment: Rob thanks!  Text was very large to fit here.  Here is the link: http://textuploader.com/d9hvu I appreciate your help.  The button (plus sign) is before "Tap (+) sign to add a new..." on the screen.

Comment: Look at the first line of the output. It says your `UIWindow` is 320x480, which is the screen size of the iPhone 4S and earlier. All iPads have a screen resolution of at least 768x1024. Why is your window the wrong size?

Comment: Rob, thanks for the info!  This project was originally written in 2010 using xcode 3.x.  I now ported it in to xcode 8.2.1.  What would be the "correct" way to set the views to 768x1024?  I have just been doing C# since then and now getting back into this project.  Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question to describe how you create your window. If it's in code, show the code.